# Prove Theorem 2.2 for the case that β is infinite, that is, $R(T) = span({T(v) : v ∈ β})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

> Prove Theorem 2.2 for the case that β is infinite, that is, $R(T) =
>  span({T(v) : v ∈ β})$.

$span({T(v) : v ∈ β})\subset R(T)$ can be deduced trivially.  How do I prove converse? For finite-dimensional vector space, it can be proved without any confusion. How do I prove it for an infinite dimensional case? I got the solution from solution manual.

**My Doubt:-**
I don't understand why did they assume $v\in V $ has a finite linear combination of elements in $(T(\beta)$?

Solution given in solution manual
[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFMAm.png)

Comment: A basis is in particular a generating set. A set $\beta$ of vectors generates the space $V$ if every vector $v\in V$ is equal to a linear combination of elements of $\beta$. A linear combination is by definition a finite sum, or if you like a sum $\sum_{w\in \beta}a_ww$ in which all but finitely many $a_w$ are zero.

Comment: Then where we use the assumption infinite dimensional in the proof?

Comment: Nowhere. That is the point of the exercise; to show you that the theorem didn't need to talk about dimension. Actually, from the proof you can see that the theorem didn't even need to talk about bases. $\beta$ only needs to be a generating set of $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this question is about a basis on vector space.

Consider a vector space $V$ s.t. $V$ is set of all polynomial over $(0,1)$. If we allow the infinite sum, then $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\ x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}$ is not polynomial.

Comment: What about $C[o,1]$?

Comment: If $f_n=n$ is a constant, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ f_n =\infty$ so that it is not in $C[0,1]$

Comment: My question was can we able to write the elements of a infinite dimensional V.S as the linear combination of finite elemnts of the basis?

Comment: It is a definition of element in vector space.